# How does modify value on the same memory's address will delete the previous value? "OVERWRITTEN concept on PC's mode operation"

Tags: c, memory, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm new on world of computing and computers ..I'm developing in C programming and really every time I get stuck in my thinking how really PC delete the old value if we modified it by new value, I mean:
lets assume I write on C like this

```
int i=6;
i=7;
```

then the value of i is 7, I know why because we have modified the old value by 7, but how does really the PC delete the previous value? I could believe just in "the previous value overwritten and it will be deleted" but I'm curious to know how really it's deleted by assigning modified value?

Is it like magic? still weird for me .. a good explanation would be really appreciated to convince me how PC use overwritten mode operation to delete previous values once we modifying on the same memory's address ..

Comment: I think when you say "PC" you mean "personal computer", not assembly "program counter" or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers have a finite amount of storage.  They overwrite that storage.  It's *not* like a SSA model where every assignment creates a new variable.  Computers really do change the value of an existing storage location.

The C language is defined in terms of every variable having its own memory location.  Assigning a new value does *not* change the address.  It's not a reference to a new immutable value, it's really mutating the storage for `int i`.  **Writing a new value implicitly destroys the previous contents of a variable**.  It doesn't *go* anywhere.

You can look at an example of using pointers to see that after `int *p = &i;` the value you get from `*p` changes after you do `i=7;`  Or google up a tutorial on C pointers for more detail.

---

**It's not "magic", just electrically how a memory cell naturally works**.  e.g. a single [flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) can be changed from one state to another by applying an input signal along with a reset signal that tells it to forget its old value.

---

**A physical analogy is a piece of paper with a pencil and eraser,** *not* a big stack of fresh index cards.  The "consumable" (pencil lead and eraser) is just electrical power.  (Or more specifically, electric charge in CMOS logic.  Some other kinds of digital logic require current to *flow* continuously, using a lot of power.)

---

CPU registers are typically made of SRAM (static RAM), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory#Writing.  One cell is usually made of 6 transistors, for example, like a flip-flop but fancier and with no current flowing except when a new value is set.  This stores 1 bit, and can be written with a new value any number of times, by applying a write-enable signal to update the SRAM cell to the value in its input line.

Actual main-memory is typically made of [DRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory), where bits are stored as charge on a capacitor.  Every time you read it, you have to refresh this charge, but it's still the same concept of a fixed location that can be written with new values.

Comment: but what do you mean implicitly destroy the old value? what do you mean by "implicitly" .. didn't understand this term .. do you mean actually we are not destroying the old value/deleting the old value?

Comment: can you gimme another words or term equal to your understandings of using "implicitly" ?

Comment: @Tony.M: Imagine a physical switch.  Setting the light switch to "on" destroys the old value without you having to do anything.  There isn't an old "off" value anywhere.  I said "implicitly" because it's not a separate step you have to take in the process; you don't have to "erase" the old value first before you can set a new value; you just set the value and the old value disappears.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I believe it may be overcomplicated given the question and implied knowledge of OP. I would like to simplify it a bit, hopefully this helps him. When you build your code, it's of course turned into machine language, and we're going to assume x86_64 for the sake of brevity. There are only two ways to access memory -- registers (SRAM) or address (DRAM). Note that local variables are often stored on the stack which would be DRAM.

Comment: That code may be compiled in several different ways. Ignoring optimization for a second (first line is dead code and would be optimized out) let's take a look at what will happen. Line 1 will move the value 6 to either a register or memory address. Line 2 uses the same local variables so it will reset that same register or memory address to the value 7.

Comment: Oh, hey, I just noticed this is the same Peter from my last post. The low level boards are a small world. lol

Comment: @PickleRick: In real C implementations for "normal" CPUs, you could compile with optimization disabled in which case `i` will be spilled to the stack.  Or you could compile with optimization enabled in which case the `i=6` initializer is irrelevant because nothing reads it.  It'll be optimized away.  Along with the `7` if nothing reads that either.  To keep the answer short, I just talked about the C abstract machine: the *model* of computation that C is defined in terms of.  And also how hardware works to explain the physical basis of computing.

Comment: @PickleRick: And yeah, the asm / low-level tags are a small group; welcome to the club :)

Comment: @PickleRick: Fun fact which I omitted from the answer: in information theory + thermodynamics, the only part of computing that necessarily costs energy is destroying the old value of a storage location.  Reversible operations in theory don't have to cost any energy.  https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/revcomp/faq.html#zeroenergy and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing.  In practice everything always costs energy (unless it optimizes away entirely :P)